# use javascript,php, or html to reload a page when the URL changes

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to get a page that when the URL changes it immediately reloads and uses the parameters in the URL.
The first url is : `http://localhost/victorphp/Callvisor/bp/index.php`

This does not work for some reason:

```
<a href="http://localhost/victorphp/Callvisor/bp/index.php?section=user&Mpage=tools" onClick="window.location.reload" >
Test
</a>
```

When I click on the link the page reloads without the parameters.

Comment: Can't you use the parameters on the first load of the new page? Why do you need a second page load?  Or do you want to intercept the link and add the parameters to the url without needing to load from the server at all?

Comment: I am trying to get my page to reload once the URL

Comment: @Dcdanny What i mean is when my URL changes from the first URL to the second it should reload my page and keep the parameters in the URL

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. An HTML link should cause a page reload when you click it anyway... Are you changing the url with javascript? Is your link inside an iframe?

Comment: I don't really get the point of setting a href and also execute location.reload(). Which is it? When someone clicks the link, should it go to the URL or should it reload the current page? Or are they the same? If you want to go to the href, then just remove the `onclick`. If that's not the URL you want to load, then change it to be the URL you want to load? If you explain why you need this and what it's for, things might be clearer for us.

Comment: Why not just check for those GET parameters onload and fill them in with your defaults if they're null?

Comment: the problem is that the page will not reload even if I did that I already tried it

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Without any more context, I have no idea what you're actually are trying to do or what happens. Please edit the question and include a more detailed explanation of what you're trying to do (take it step by step), why you need it (so we can give better suggestions) and what currently happens. Be detailed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add id to your link

```
<a href="http://localhost/victorphp/Callvisor/bp/index.php?section=user&Mpage=tools" id="1" onClick="loadUrl(this)" >
Test
</a>
```

Create function loadUrl() in your js file

```
function loadUrl(lid){
var url=document.getElementById(lid.id).href;
location.href=url;
}
```